# Incrementing a field with a Ruby on Rails call back

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model `Graph` with fields `name` and `version`. I want the name and version to be unique so have declared

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: :version
```

When a new Graph object is created, if it has the same name as a previous Graph object, then I want the version to be incremented. However, I do not want the version incremented upon update. So far I have implemented this with a call back

```
class Graph < ApplicationRecord
      enum preservation_status: [:unlocked, :locked]
      validates_presence_of :name
      validates_presence_of :version
      validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: :version

      has_many :graph_points, dependent: :destroy
      belongs_to :data_set
            validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: :version
            before_validation :set_version, on: :create
            private
            def set_version
                  graphs = Graph.where(name: name)
                  return if graphs.empty?
                  self.version = graphs.maximum(:version) + 1
            end
```

This does not work. If a graph of that name exists, then the code appears to enter an infinite loop and I have to restart the server. How to I fix this?

For instance, if I have have one existing graph with name 'Plot_quick Male', with version = 1, then try to create a new graph with the same name, the sql that results is below:

```
   (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "graphs" WHERE "graphs"."name" = $1  [["name", "Plot_quick Male "]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT MAX("graphs"."version") FROM "graphs" WHERE "graphs"."name" = $1  [["name", "Plot_quick Male "]]
  Graph Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "graphs" WHERE "graphs"."name" = $1 AND "graphs"."version" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["name", "Plot_quick Male "], ["version", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

and then the server hangs.

The default value for version is set in the schema i.e.

```
t.integer  "version",             default: 0
```

Comment: What causes the infinite loop? Have you tried putting a breakpoint (`byebug`)?

Comment: I have tried using binding.pry, and it appears to happen directly after the line ```self.version = graphs.maximum(:version) + 1```, so my guess is happening when the validation is triggered.  Another strange thing is that it happens in development mode but not test mode, but that might be because the data is not identical.

Comment: is your `Graph` model complete?? Have you more relevant code? Which version of rails are you using? I copy/paste your code in a new project and it works fine

Comment: There is quite a bit to the full model, but I have added in anything that might have do do with the create process.  The instance methods look standard, although there is one called ```export```, perhaps that is reserved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to eliminate the problem from development by deleting all versions of graph and recreating new ones. It might have been something strange in some of the graphs that were created with earlier versions of the code.

I will mark this is the answer for the time being, but if anyone comes up with a answer that make sense, I will have a look.